# Power analysis for two-way repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, statistical-power, effect-size, two-way

I am trying to run a post-hoc power analysis on a previously conducted study, in which the results were analysed through a two-way repeated measures ANOVA (I used a 2x2 within-subjects design). Through the previous analysis, I already have the effect size (Cohen's f), sample size, and alpha, so based on these measures, I want to calculate the power.
However, I'm struggling to find out how to do a power analysis for two-way repeated measures ANOVA.
The 'pwr' function in r seems to support only power analysis for one-way ANOVA, and so does the other ones.
I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in G*Power software, or in R using the WebPower package:

```
library(WebPower)

wp.rmanova(n = 30, ng = 2, nm = 2, f = 0.36, alpha = 0.05, power = NULL, type = 1)
```

where n = number of participants, ng = nr of groups, nm = nr of measurements, f=Cohen's f and type=1 specifies that you want power for the repeated effect (0 (default) is for between-groups effect and 2 is for within-between interaction).

---

Edited to add - it seems that Gpower's default for specifying Cohen's f is different from WebPower's default. I got identical results when I went to GPower options and chose "effect size specifications - as in Cohen (1988))"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I have additional questions. First of all, I'm not sure what the nm(#of measurement) means. Also, I am trying to do an analysis two within-subject factors, but doesn't wp.rmanova only support either analysis for one within-subject factor or one within and one between-subject factor?

Comment: number of measurements refers to the number of levels of the within-person factor. But unfortunately, it seems WebPower can't handle an interaction between two within-person factors. (if you had 4 entirely different repeated measures conditions that all participants went through, you could specify nm = 4, ng=1, type=1, but wp.rmanova doesn't seem to take 2 within-person factors).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comment! Btw, do you know any R packages that support power analysis with 2 within-subject factors by any chance?

Comment: Sorry, I don't :( It's curious that that option does not seem to be readily available in any software (but I don't know G*Power well, it might be possible there). Using simulations is an option too.

Comment: I dont' think it's available in G*Power but thanks a lot. Much appreciated.

Comment: For what is worth, I think this is now possible using the Superpower package in R, see: https://aaroncaldwell.us/SuperpowerBook/repeated-measures-anova.html (scroll to the part 4.2: Part 2).